# this context in javascript object with Scope and context

Tags: javascript

```
const user = {
    name:'mdv',
    places : ['rio', 'new', 'aust'],
    printPlacesLived: function () {
        return this.places.map((place)=>this.name +'has lived in '+place)
    }
}
```

**this  refers to the context in which they were created in ** (according to my knowledge)

2) so that is why  inside my anonymous function  this.name is working correctly

```
const user = {
    name:'mdv',
    places : ['rio', 'new', 'aust'],
    printPlacesLived:  () =>{
        return this.places.map((place)=>this.name +'has lived in '+place)
    }
}
```

Same method i have  changed printPlacesLived to the arrow funtion so according to the defination

**this  refers to the context in which they were created in**

1) Now i am getting places undefined if the definition is correct,  printPlacesLived  is created inside my user object so the refrence must be to places but not happening why ?

2) I am confused  i studied some other  definitions of  arrow functions and  this(it is mentioned that this retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's )

Now for printPlacesLived lexical context is name and places plese help me where did i go wrong

Comment: Don't change your question totally after people have already answered it. Rather ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry but now it makes more sense  because i have  tryed to keep my doubt in small code fomat

Comment: Like I said, please ask a new question. People have put their effort to the original question, and this edit totally changing the question invalidates the existing answer(s).

Comment: ok  but i don't know how to roll back

Comment: I can do it for you. You can find the versions by clicking the "edited" link below the question.

Comment: let a = {
         thisScope : this,
         arrow : ()=> this  
        }
    
    a.thisScope == a.arrow 
    false 
plese explain why it returned false  both are refreing to window object only

Answer (score 0):

Unlike regular functions, arrow functions do not have their own `this`. The value of this inside an arrow function remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of this in the closest non-arrow parent function.

```
let me = { 
 name: "Ashutosh Verma", 
 thisInArrow:() => { 
 console.log("My name is " + this.name); // no 'this' binding here 
 }, 
 thisInRegular(){ 
 console.log("My name is " + this.name); // 'this' binding works here 
 } 
};
me.thisInArrow(); 
me.thisInRegular();
```

[image]

Comment: I have changed the question please go through

Answer (score -1):

1. Your 1 code is working good, need some corrections
2. In arrow function This aims to level up